# Making css circles at the bottom of an image responsive and at a fixed position

Tags: css, slider, geometry

I have a problem I can't figure out in css. At the bottom of an imageslider I have three circles, but they need to be a bit responsive so that everyone on a laptop from 13' till 21' can see them at their exact position. But when I resize the screen, these circles loose their position and will be placed a bit higher or lower. [Here is the example](http://www.creativecodes.be/filip/) I am talking about, you will see when you resize the screen, the circles are not in their original good position, at the bottom of the image. 
[I am working towards this](http://www.creativecodes.be/filip/home.jpg). The code I have is the following:

**CSS**

```
.bxslider {

margin: 0; 
padding:0;  

}

#bijschrift {

position: relative;
left: 65%;
height: auto;
bottom: 250px;
float: left;    
z-index: 9999;
}

#bijschrifthoofd {  
z-index: 9999;
opacity: 0.8;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
    background-color: #212121;
}
#bijschrifthoofd span {
    width:  auto;
        color: white;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-weight: 500;
line-height: 45px;
font-size: 150%;

}
#bijschriftonder {
z-index: 9999;
opacity: 0.8;
margin-top: 10px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
    background-color: #212121;
    float: left;
}
#bijschriftonder span {
    width: auto;
        color: white;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-weight:100;
line-height: 45px;
font-size: 22px;

}
#cirkelcontainer {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
position: relative;
bottom: 200px;
z-index: 9999;
display: block;

}
.circle
{
    display:table-cell;
width:80px;
height:80px;
border-radius:40px;
font-size:16px;
color:white;
vertical-align: top;
text-align:center;
background:#00ccff;
float: left;

font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 22px;
line-height: 80px;
}
.circle2 {
    display:table-cell;
    margin-left: 2%;
    z-index: 9999;
width:80px;
height:80px;
border-radius:40px;
font-size:16px;
color:white;
vertical-align: top;
text-align:center;
background:#e05c50;
float: left;

font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 22px;
line-height: 80px;
}
.circle3 {
    display:table-cell;
    margin-left: 10%;
    z-index: 9999;
width:80px;
height:80px;
border-radius:40px;
font-size:16px;
color:white;
vertical-align: top;
text-align:center;
background:#0099cc;
float: left;

font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 22px;
line-height: 80px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="bxslider" >
  <li><img src="fotos/Untitled-5.jpg" title="Funky roots" /></li>
  <li><img src="fotos/Untitled-4.jpg" title="The long and winding road" /></li>
  <li><img src="fotos/Untitled-3.jpg" title="Happy trees" /></li>

</ul>
<div id="bijschrift">
<div id="bijschrifthoofd"><span>UW SPRINGPLANK NAAR INSPIRATIE</span></div>
<div id="bijschriftonder"><span>En authentieke waterpret</span></div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div id="cirkelcontainer">
    <div class="circle">O</div>
    <div class="circle2">IB</div>
    <div class="circle3">T</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite obvious: I  had to position the circles to absolute so it wouldn't affect the position of my next divs, and add a 'margin-left: -width px' to it. In this case: "margin-left: -50px;".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where is the "exact position" of the circles. I'm assuming it's over the image at the bottom, like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Y65mW/1/

So I changed the circles Html like this:

```
 <div id="circle1" class="circle">O</div>
```

and the Css so we can use a single circle style definition:

```
.circle {
  position: absolute;
  width:80px;
  height:80px;
  border-radius:40px;
  ...
}
#circle1 {
  left: 60px;
  background:#00ccff;
```

}

You should still add a 'min-width' property to the whole site.

---

I updated the solution here http://jsfiddle.net/Y65mW/3/embedded/result/

Comment: thank you very much for your quick reply. The circles though, should be half over the image as you can see in the design I have included in my post.